How can I individually identify and handle reply actions for each comment in SwiftUI?
I've implemented a comment section in SwiftUI where users can leave comments and reply to them. I have encountered an issue regarding handling replies. When a user taps the reply button to respond to a comment, I enable the reply functionality by toggling a boolean property in the view model (viewModel.isReply). However, when a user taps the reply button to respond to another user's comment, it immediately disables the reply button for all comments. This behavior is logical since I'm toggling the isReply property globally.
My goal is to enable users to reply to individual comments and switch between replying to different comments seamlessly. Currently, I'm toggling the isReply property to send data from the view model. How can I modify my approach to recognize and handle each comment's reply action separately? I want users to be able to cancel their reply to a specific comment by tapping the reply button again.
MainCommentView:
struct MainCommentView: View {
    var data: Comment
    @ObservedObject var viewModelObserved: PostCommentsViewModel
    @State private var showReplies: Bool = false
    @FocusState var isTextFieldFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading) {
            HStack(alignment:.top) {
                // Views for displaying user's profile picture and comment text
                
                // Reply button
                Button {
                    viewModelObserved.commentId = data.id ?? "unknown"
                    if viewModelObserved.commentId == data.id ?? "unknown" {
                        viewModelObserved.isReply.toggle()
                    }
                    viewModelObserved.mention = "@\(data.user?.firstName ?? "unknown")"
                    viewModelObserved.commentText = "\(viewModelObserved.mention) "
                    isTextFieldFocused = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Reply")
                        .font(.ubuntu(name: .ubuntuRegular, size: 12))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                }
                
                // Displaying timestamp of the comment
                Text("\(viewModel.formattedTime(dateString: data.createdAt ?? ""))")
                    .font(.ubuntu(name: .ubuntuRegular, size: 11))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                
            }
            // Button for showing/hiding replies
            Button(showReplies ? "— Hide Replies (\(data.countReplies ?? 0))" : "— Show Replies(\(data.countReplies ?? 0))") {
                viewModel.commentId = data.id ?? "unknown"
                viewModel.getReplies()
                showReplies.toggle()
            }
            .font(.ubuntu(name: .ubuntuRegular, size: 14))
            .foregroundStyle(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
            
            // Displaying replies if they exist and 'showReplies' is true
            if showReplies {
                if let repliesData = viewModel.repliesModel?.data?.comments {
                    ForEach(repliesData, id:\.id) { reply in
                        RepliesView(data: reply)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    }
}


ViewModel:
 func addComment(onComplete: (()->())? = nil) {
        isLoading = true
        
        
        var parameters: [String: Any] = [
            parameters for main comment
        ]
        
        
        if self.isReply {
            parameters for reply
        }
   
        functionForSendingData()
    }

If anyone can suggest something, I am grateful!

This is because showReplies  property can be changed each click of comment.  You can add an additional property to the Comment model called isReplying, like this:
struct Comment {
   var id: String
   var isReplying: Bool = false
   // Other properties you have
}


In your ViewModel, define comments as a @Published object so you can detect changes instantly on your view. Also, add another function to change the comment model's isReplying state:
final class PostCommentsViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var comments: [Comment]

    func toggleReply(for commentId: String) {
        if let index = comments.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == commentId }) {
            comments[index].isReplying.toggle()
        }
    }
}


Lastly, in your view, you can call the necessary function from your ViewModel:
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            // Views for displaying user's profile picture and comment text
                
            // Reply button
            Button {
                viewModelObserved.commentId = data.id ?? "unknown"
                if viewModelObserved.commentId == data.id ?? "unknown" {
                    viewModel.toggleReply(for: comment.id)
                }
                viewModelObserved.mention = "@\(data.user?.firstName ?? "unknown")"
                viewModelObserved.commentText = "\(viewModelObserved.mention) "
                isTextFieldFocused = true
            } label: {
                Text("Reply")
                    .font(.ubuntu(name: .ubuntuRegular, size: 12))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
            }
        }
        // Other functions
    }
}


